# Python 3.3 PEP 418 example gives 'namespace' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, namespaces, python-3.x, python-3.3

The beta of Python 3.3 is out and wonderful.

The newly reworked [time](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html) module has the [get_clock_info](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.get_clock_info) method to get information about the platform's many logical clocks. [PEP 418](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/) describes the new time module.

When I try and run one of the example programs referenced in PEP 418, [clock_resolution.py](http://hg.python.org/peps/file/tip/pep-0418/clock_resolution.py), I get `TypeError: 'namespace' object is not iterable` on line 54 below:

```
46 clocks = ['clock', 'perf_counter', 'process_time']
47 if hasattr(time, 'monotonic'):
48     clocks.append('monotonic')
49 clocks.append('time')
50 for name in clocks:
51     func = getattr(time, name)
52     test_clock("%s()" % name, func)
53     info = time.get_clock_info(name)
54     if 'precision' in info:
55         print("- announced precision: %s" % format_duration(info['precision']))
56     print("- implementation: %s" % info['implementation'])
57     print("- resolution: %s" % format_duration(info['resolution']))
```

'info' on line 53 contains:

```
>>> info
namespace(adjustable=True, implementation='gettimeofday()', monotonic=False, resolution=1e-06)
```

So how does one iterate over a namespace object?

Comment: You should open an issue on the Python bug tracker about this: http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: @NedDeily: Which has the bug tho? Python 3.3 or the example code in PEP 418? It would seem to me that you should be able to iterate over a namespace object, but I do not see this documented..

Comment: I think the issue to document is that the sample program in the PEP no longer works because of a change in the implementation of the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to iterate the object; you just want to test for presence of an attribute.  Two ways:

```
# "easier to get forgiveness than permission" approach
try:
    print(info.precision)
except AttributeError:
    pass

# "look before you leap" approach
if hasattr(info, "precision"):
    print(info.precision)
```

The `in` test is used to check if something is in a dictionary, a list, a tuple, or some other sequence.  In the general case, `in` will try to iterate something to find the value (`dict` and `set` are exceptions; Python special-cases them for efficiency).  But `info` is an instance of a class that doesn't support iteration.

You could, if you wished, do this:

```
# alternate "look before you leap"
if "precision" in info.__dict__:
    print(info.precision)
```

Attributes actually are stored in a `dict` instance member variable named `.__dict__`.

EDIT: @DSM wrote a comment that showed an alternative to the above.  The built-in function `vars()` will return the `.__dict__` member variable, so this is equivalent to the above:

```
# nicer alternate "look before you leap"
if "precision" in vars(info):
    print(info.precision)
```

Comment: Ah, beat me.  I'll also mention that using `info = vars(time.get_clock_info(name))` instead would make the current code work by making `info` into a dictionary instead of a namespace.

Comment: @DSM, thanks for that.  I knew about referencing `x.__dict__` but I didn't know about `vars(x)`.  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Just a clarification: Python doesn't special-case dict and set - any class implementing `__contains__` will use it when checking `in`. You can do that in your own classes, too. Only if `__contains__` is not implemented, Python will resort to iteration (which can also be directly supported, or fall back to `__getitem__`).